# Masstransit logging middleware

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, asp.net-web-api2, masstransit

I have problem with applying middleware for logging in masstransit. I wanted to log every message which is published to the bus. So I follow these steps which I found here: http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/advanced/middleware/custom.html 
and then I endup with something like this:

```
public static class MassTransitLoggerExtenions
{
    public static void UseLogger<T>(this IPipeConfigurator<T> configurator,ILoggingBusControl loggingBusControl)
        where T : class, PipeContext
    {
        configurator.AddPipeSpecification(new ExceptionLoggerSpecification<T>(loggingBusControl));
    }
}


 public class ExceptionLoggerSpecification<T> :
    IPipeSpecification<T>
    where T : class, PipeContext
{
    private readonly ILoggingBusControl loggingBusControl;

    public ExceptionLoggerSpecification(ILoggingBusControl loggingBusControl)
    {
        this.loggingBusControl = loggingBusControl;
    }
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate()
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<ValidationResult>();
    }

    public void Apply(IPipeBuilder<T> builder)
    {
        builder.AddFilter(new ExceptionLoggerFilter<T>(loggingBusControl));
    }

}

 public class ExceptionLoggerFilter<T> : IFilter<T> where T : class, PipeContext
{
    private readonly ILoggingBusControl loggingBusControl;

    public ExceptionLoggerFilter(ILoggingBusControl loggingBusControl)
    {
        this.loggingBusControl = loggingBusControl;
    }

    public void Probe(ProbeContext context)
    {
    }

    public async Task Send(T context, IPipe<T> next)
    {
        throw new Exception("Foo");
        try
        {
            await next.Send(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }


}
```

There is my simple abstraction over `IBusControl`

```
 public class LoggingBusControl : ILoggingBusControl
{
    private readonly IBusControl busControl;
    public LoggingBusControl()
    {
        busControl = GetBusControl();
        busControl.Start();
    }

    private static IBusControl GetBusControl()
    {
        var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(x =>
        {
            var host = x.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/#/queues/%2F/logging_queue"), h =>
            {
                h.Username("guest");
                h.Password("guest");
            });
        });
        return busControl;
    }


    public void Log<T>(T log) where T : ILog
    {
        busControl.Publish<ILog>(log);
    }
}
```

Usage

```
 builder.Register(context =>
            {
                var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(rabbitMqConfig =>
                {
                    var host = rabbitMqConfig.Host(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RabbitMQHost"]), h =>
                    {
                        h.Username("guest");
                        h.Password("guest");
                    });
                    var logger = context.Resolve<ILoggingBusControl>();
                    rabbitMqConfig.UseLogger(logger);
                });

                return busControl;
            })
            .SingleInstance()
            .As<IBusControl>()
            .As<IBus>()
            .OnActivated(args => args.Instance.Start());
```

Then I inject IBusControl in controller constructor

```
 public OrderController(IOrderService orderService,IBusControl busControl)
    {
        this.orderService = orderService;
        this.busControl = busControl;

    }
```

Messages are publised correctly and `ExceptionLoggerFilter`, `ExceptionLoggerSpecification` constructors are called, but methods `Probe` and `Send` in `ExceptionLoggerFilter` are never invoked. What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: What is the point in configuring the bus in this `ILoggingBusControl` thing, whatever is it for, and in the container registration?

Comment: `ILoggingBusControl` is shared across multiple web services. Just for centralized logging. But this have no impact for my problem. Without it, this doesnt work either.

Comment: What is the code of `UseLogger` custom extension method?

Comment: I've post it also. Look at `MassTransitLoggerExtenions` class

Comment: I might suggest that `OnActivated` is not really a good choice there. I would also suggest using Audit for this purpose http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/advanced/audit/. You just need to implement the `IMessageAuditStore` interface (it has one method).

Comment: Thanks, I will look at it. Could you please tell me why call `OnActivated` its not good choice? I used it for start the bus for the first request of `IBusControl`.It is registered as singleton and this registration happens in 'Global.asax' so it called only once when app starts.

Comment: Usually for web apps you can call `bus.Start()` to the `Application_Start` and then `bus.Stop` in the finalisation code. Your current solution does not specify the explicit moment of the bus to be started, which is not a good choice; neither it stops the bus, which is bad. Also, Autofac specifically mentions that `OnActivated` should be rarely used (read - should be avoided).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151282/discussion-between-tjdillashaw-and-alexey-zimarev).

Comment: Broken link fix to MT **Audit** page and `IMessageAuditStore` : https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/audit.html

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified if you try to use the middleware for messages being sent vs messages being consumed, but from your question it appears that you try to use it for messages being sent.

If this is the case (or for anyone that comes across this question with the same issue) please note that the middleware described in [the Mass Transit documentation](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/advanced/middleware/custom.html) works only for messages being consumed, not for messages being sent.

For logging messages, especially messages being sent, you are better off using [the Mass Transit audit feature](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/advanced/audit/) as @Alexey Zimarev mentioned in his comment.