# MassTransit How to create a custom middleware or a pipeline when i publish or consume messages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, masstransit

I use a Net 5 API which publishes and consumes messages via MassTransit.
The problem is I try to find a way to create a custom middleware or a pipeline for both cases(publish consume) to measure the time which published or consumed the messages...

I tried to create a custom middleware exactly as the documentation presentation https://masstransit-project.com//advanced/middleware/custom.html but the problem is when I try to publish the message cannot invoke the methods. According to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45545846/masstransit-logging-middleware) it is only for consumed messages.
Have someone any idea how to create a pipeline or middleware for both cases(publish consume)?

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see, you simply need to measure (log?) the time at when messages are published and consumed - if so, you could use [observers](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/observers.html). Specifically, [publish observers](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/observers.html#published-messages) and [consume observers](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/observers.html#consumed-messages).

E.g., an example of the consume observer would be:

```
public class ConsumeObserver : IConsumeObserver
{    
    Task IConsumeObserver.PreConsume<T>(ConsumeContext<T> context)
    {
        // called before the consumer's Consume method is called
    }

    Task IConsumeObserver.PostConsume<T>(ConsumeContext<T> context)
    {
        // called after the consumer's Consume method is called
        // -> Log DateTime.Now with message details found in context. <-
    }

    Task IConsumeObserver.ConsumeFault<T>(ConsumeContext<T> context, Exception exception)
    {
        // called if the consumer's Consume method throws an exception
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods, `ConfigureSend` and `ConfigurePublish`, which are accessed via the `IBusFactoryConfigurator` where filters can be added to the send and publish pipelines respectively.

Comment: i am a little bit confused, what about the consumed messages? is it configuresend?

Comment: The consume pipeline is configured by default, thus the `ConsumeContext` filter type. How is that not obvious?